# MonoDevelop 3.1.1 can't find System.Xml.Linq

Tags: c#, linq, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.mobile

I just downloaded the trial version of "Mono for Android"/MonoDevelop 3.1.1 for Mac OS X. I am trying to parse some XML using XDocument. But I can't seem to find the import I need:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

I get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.xml'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Opening System.Xml reference under References in Solution Explorer shows that there are no Linq in it:

```
System.Xml
 - References
   - mscorlib
   - System
 - System.Xml
 - System.Xml.Schema
 - System.Xml.Serialization
 - System.Xml.XPath
 - System.Xml.Xsl
```

Any ideas?

**Edit: More info:**

- Runtime: Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)
- Mono for Android: 4.4.55 (Evaluation)
- Monotouch: Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed
- Operating System: Mac OS X 10.8.2

System.Xml:

- [assembly: AssemblyVersion ("2.0.5.0")]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add the `System.Xml.Linq` assembly to your project references; the `System.Xml.Linq` isn't in `System.Xml`, but has an assembly of itself.

Right click `References` in your solution window, and select `Edit References`. Add `System.Xml.Linq` there.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. Where do I find it? Could not find it searching on my computer.

Comment: @Sunkas - If its not listed in the references per the screenshot that Antonijn posted then its not installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

on the commandline

```
mcs /reference:System.Xml.Linq.dll ...
```

works for me